# ROS Camera Calibration Extract Completion Percentage

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, camera-calibration

I'm trying to extract the completion percentage of the [camera_calibration](https://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) package, in ros noetic.

I was thinking of publishing the results from `compute_goodenough()` function in a new rostopic and then through a Subscriber print the results but it's kind of difficult due to the need of separate threads.

If anyone has done it in the past please let me know, any other solutions are also acceptable.